# Slider value - Sencha Architect

Tags: extjs, slider, sencha-touch, sencha-architect

I have tried to get the slider value, Instead of numeric value. Im getting as array object as a value, How to rectify it.

Eg:

```
xtype: 'sliderfield',
                        html: '<span class="not-like">Not Likely</span> <span class="like">Like</span>',
                        label: '',
                        name: 'like',
                        maxValue: 10,
                        value: '1'
                    }
```

Instead of

```
xtype: 'sliderfield',
                        html: '<span class="not-like">Not Likely</span> <span class="like">Like</span>',
                        label: '',
                        name: 'like',
                        maxValue: 10,
                        value: [1]
                    }
```

using Sencha architect version:
3.1.0.1934

Any help in getting the slider value.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you asking for Thump index value.
OnDrag and Onchage event you get the thumb Index and value.

```
OnDragPointSlider : function(sliderfield, sl, thumb, e, eOpts) {
    var slider = sliderfield.getComponent();
    var index = slider.getThumbIndex(thumb);
    var newValue = slider.getValue()[index];
},
```